$\int _0 ^x \frac {g(u)}{u+f(x)} du=1 $ then $f ' (0) =?$

Given
$\int _0 ^x \frac {g(u)}{u+f(x)} du=1  $ where $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[0 , \infty ) , f >0 $ on $(0 , \infty)$ and $g>0 $ on $[0 , \infty )$ then $f'(0) $ is equal to
$(a)\space \frac 1{e^{\frac 1{g(0)}} -1} $
$(b) \space e^{g(0)} -1$
$(c) \space   {e^{\frac 1{g(0)}} -1} $
$(d) \space $ Does Not Exist.
My Ideas
$(1)$ From the given integral equation , we can write $\int _0 ^x \frac {g(u)}{1+\frac u{f(x)}} du= f(x)   $
If $f(x)>x$ , then one can use the G.P series expansion so as to get
$f(x)= \int _0 ^x g(u) \Sigma _{i\ge 0} \big( \frac {(-u)}{f(x)}\big) ^i du   $
$f(x)= \Sigma _{i\ge 0} \big( \frac {-1}{f(x)}\big) ^i    \int _0 ^x g(u)u^i du $ , By Uniform Convergence ( ? )
But this is leading to nowhere fruitful .
(2) Take $g(x)=k>0$ , a constant .
Then putting in the integral and solving for $f(x)$ , we get
$f(x)= \frac x{e^{\frac 1{k}} -1} $
This gives answer similar to $(a)$  but what to do for any $g$?
I think we have to show $g$ as necessarily constant .
Hints Please .

Okay, first of all we observe that $f(0)$ has to be zero, otherwise the function $g(u)/(u+f(0))$ has no discontinuity in zero, the integral is not a improper integral, and so we would have for $x=0$ the equality $0=1$.
Now we try a change of variable $y:=\frac{u}{x}$
$$ \int_0^x \frac{g(u)}{u+f(x)}du =\int_{0}^1 \frac{g(xy)}{y+\frac{f(x)}{x}}dy=1$$
Now we take the limit for $x\to 0$ (the limit of the integral is the integral of the limit) and we obtain by continuity of $g$ at $t=0$ that
$$ \int_0^1\frac{g(0)}{y+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}}dy=\int_0^1\frac{g(0)}{y+f'(0)}dy=1 \implies g(0)\ln\left(y+f'(0) \right)]_0^1=1 \implies \ln\left(\frac{1+f'(0)}{f'(0)}\right)=\frac{1}{g(0)} \implies \frac{1}{f'(0)}+1=e^{\frac{1}{g(0)}} \implies f'(0)=\frac{1}{{e^\frac{1}{g(0)}-1}}.$$
The correct answer should be $a)$.
However, this works only if you suppose that the derivative of $f$ at $0$ exists, otherwise I don't know if this argument still works. We can think on it if you want.
$\bf{Update.}$ I thought there was a problem coming from the question itself and I was a bit confused. We observed that $f(0)$ has to be zero. However, since $g(x)>0$ on $[0,+\infty)$, so let us say $g(x)=1$ constantly, then we would have the integral $\int_0^x \frac{1}{u+f(x)}du$ that can be divergent:
$$ \int_0^x \frac{1}{u+f(x)}du=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_\epsilon^x \frac{1}{u+f(x)}du=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\ln\left(\frac{x+f(x)}{\epsilon+f(x)}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{x}{f(x)}+1\right)$$
Thus the question makes sense if $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)$ is asintotically equivalent to $x$ for $x\to 0$ in that case. However, the question should be well-posed in any case and the right answer should be $a)$.

Your answer is very satisfactory . Just if you can clarify a bit about the reason for interchanging of integral and limit :).

One moment one moment, there is a problem from the beginning. Let me think more

However, on the question about the interchanging, just take the difference of the integrals (that at $f(x)/x$ and that at $f'(0)$) and prove that its absolute value is less than $\epsilon>0$. Here remember that your are using that the limit of the integrand function is $g(0)/(u+f'(0))$.

With the constant $g$ , isn't the integral coming $\ln  (1+ \frac x{f(x)} )$ . This doesn't diverge as $x\rightarrow 0$ ..right ? assuming $f$ is differentiable. Regarding your update.

What do you think of my explanation? Now I am convinced that it is okay. Let me know if I have to add the interchanging part :)

You meant asymptotically ? Very clever idea with that substitution of variable .I had thought that the integral should be improper but couldn't proceed with that . Yes please if you could add the interchanging part it would be helpful .
